# How to insert a Date Picker into a MS Excel cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datepicker

**How to insert a Date Picker into a MS Excel cell**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Tool](http://www.office-kit.com/excel_calendar/) for that or you need to do it programmaticaly like shown on MSDN using [ControlCollection.AddDateTimePicker Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4za48s1h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)